# How to see if a child or grandchild component rendered a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have a component that has several child components that will, somewhere down the component tree, render a modal. How can I tell if a modal was rendered without changing the source code of the child components?

The onClick and onCancel props for the modal are buried in grandchild components that I don't have access to, so I can't pass functions to them.

I was thinking that I could maybe check for the existence of the Modal component with ReactDOM.findDOMNode, but that needs an *instance* of a component to work if I understand the documentation correctly.

I also looked into using createRef (I'm working with a class component, so hooks are out of the question), but that wouldn't work because the child component will always exist, but the modal may or may not.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is lifting the state up. Use the context API to pass the isVisible state down to the Modal. In the modal onClick function, change the isVisible to true.
In your parent state, whenever isVisible is true, it means the modal is mounted.